# Need grep/awk/gawk to return whole section despite of break lines

Tags: linux, awk, grep, find, gawk

I have the following problem... 
I have a file, similar to this one:

```
2018-04-25: line1
2018-04-25: line2
        this is another line
        I'm a line
2018-04-25: line3
2018-04-25: line4
```

If I run: **grep 'this' test.log** the result will be:

```
    this is another line
```

but I need the result to be:

```
2018-04-25: line2
        this is another line
        I'm a line
```

because 'this is another line' is actually part of the same entry the only problem is that we have a break line there and I need my grep to ignore this break line.

- *grep -C 1 'this' test.log*
- *grep -B 1 'this' test.log*

are not really an option because I might have more lines/break lines between the start of the entry and the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using GNU awk: the date at the start of the line is the record separator. For the record containing the pattern, print the *previous* record separator and the current record.

```
gawk -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9-]{10}' '
    /this/ {sub(/^\n/, "", prev_RT); print prev_RT $0} 
    {prev_RT = RT}
' file
```

Or, more straightforward

```
awk '
    function printif() {if (record ~ /this/) print record}
    /^[0-9-]{10}/ {printif(); record = ""} 
    {record = (record ? record "\n" : "") $0} 
    END {printif()}
' file
```

Comment: Who is downvoting here? I don't see any reason for this.

Comment: Well, there is the usual suspect.

Comment: Very cryptic James. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @glennjackman A certain active member who has been downvoting all answers to questions which he has not found up to his expectations. Mostly script and shell tool relared questions.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose to punish the answerers for the "sins" of the asker. Tough love.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the input:

```
2018-04-25: line1
2018-04-25: line2
        this is another line
        I'm a line
2018-04-25: line3
2018-04-25: line4
```

You could use: `grep -A2 line2 file.log`, and it will return:

```
2018-04-25: line2
        this is another line
        I'm a line
```

The `-A` stands for `after-context`, from the man:

```
-A num, --after-context=num
         Print num lines of trailing context after each match.
```

Or you could use a mix of `-B` and `-A` if using `this` as the pattern, for example:

```
grep -B1 -A1 this file.log
```

Comment: can't really use A/B because the lines are variable

Answer (score 0):

For given sample, this would work

```
$ gawk -v ORS= -v RS='2018-' '/this/{print RS $0}' ip.txt
2018-04-25: line2
        this is another line
        I'm a line
```

- `-v ORS=` clear output record separator
- `-v RS='2018-'` set `2018-` as input record separator (assuming year is same for all records)
- `/this/{print RS $0}` if record contains `this`, print the record separator and record content

Comment: maybe make it `RS="\n2018-"`, this avoids cases where the record entry itself contains `2018-`.

Comment: @kvantour that would not cover first line... for robustness, see glenn's answer..

Comment: `RS='(^|\n)2018-'` will fix that.

Comment: @karakfa which would then require changing the print stmt or dealing with RT... which would lead to something like glenn's answer :) I was intentionally trying for simpler answer based on given sample ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another, multiline, awk version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f    

# When the line is starting with the time string
# a new record is starting...
/^[[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){2}/ {
    # Check if the (b)uffer matches /this/
    if(b~/this/)
       # ... and print it in that case
       print b

    # Empty the buffer in any case
    b="" 
}

# Append each line to the buffer
{b=b""ORS""$0}
```

It should work with any version of awk.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, we can do this also with `sed` in a more cryptic way :

```
 sed -n '/[-0-9]\{10\}:/{x;/this/p;d};H;${x;/this/p}' <file>
```

or shorter:

```
 sed -n '/[-0-9]\{10\}:/ba;H;$!b;:a;x;/this/p' <file>
```

To understand this you need to know that `sed` has two memories. The *pattern space* is where you do all operations on and the *hold space* is a long term memory. The idea is to build the record in the *hold space* by appending each line with `H`. However, if a line of the file (i.e. the *pattern space*) contains a date, check what is in the *hold space* and print if needed. The swapping of both spaces is done with `x`.

Step by step:

```
sed -n '                       # -n suppress automatic printing of pattern space
        /[-0-9]\{10\}:/ba;     # did we find a date? if so goto label 'a'
        H;                     # append the line to the hold space
        $!b;                   # did we reach EOF? if not, go to the beginning
        :a;                    # create label 'a'
        x;/this/p              # you found a date or hit the EOF
                               # swap the patterns with 'x'
                               # check if it contains /this/
                               # if so print
        ' <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` space-starting lines with `-B 1`:

```
$ grep -B 1 "^ " file
2018-04-25: line2
        this is another line
        I'm a line
```

If the space is not enough: `grep -B 1 -v "^[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}:" file`

Comment: Oh, it is an variation of @nbari's solution (++).

Answer (score 0):

From regex match to another regex:

```
awk '/line2/{f=1} f;/I\47m a line/{f=0}' file 

2018-04-25: line2
        this is another line
        I'm a line
```